# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un if que consulte si una variable arrojó o no algún resultado?

Tags: bash, bucle-for, grep

Como `$valor` está dentro de un bucle `for`, quiero preguntarle en un `if` si trajo o no el `grep` en cuestión.

```
for g in $master_ext_name_ddn; do
    VALOR=$(grep "$ruta" K?????$MES_ANTERIOR.rep | grep "$h")
done
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Quieres saber si hubo coincidencia en el grep?

Comment: no. solo si el grep arrojo un resultado el 99% de la veces no deberia de traer nada pero cuando si lo haga quiero tomar ese valor y hacer un if donde pregunte si arrojo dato o no

Comment: ve como puedes validar que $VALOR sea distinto de NULL o de " " (blanco)

Comment: así como tienes el código, es incorrecto. `$valor=grep blabla | grep bla` es incorrecto de muchas maneras: las variables se definen sin dolar inicial, los comandos se ejecutan diciendo `var=$(comando)`. Clarifica por favor este código para que sea funcional y luego indica también algún ejemplo para que quede claro qué pretendes.

Comment: @fedorqui , tienes razón, olvide quitarle el $

Comment: Guillermo: el código sigue siendo incorrecto, véase lo que dije de `var=$(comando)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto te servirá, si entendí tu pregunta.

```
for g in $master_ext_name_ddn; do

  VALOR=$(grep "$ruta" K?????$MES_ANTERIOR.rep | grep "$h")

  if [ "$VALOR" == "" ] # Cuando no hay match la variable $VALOR estará vacía
  then
    echo "no hay match"
  else
    echo "Match!"
  fi

done
```

Comment: considera siempre añadir una explicación; pues solo poner código se considera de baja calidad; la respuesta debe ser comprensible no solo para quien pregunta sino para todos los que la consulten

Comment: en el caso del codigo solo tuve que cambiar el `==` por `-eq`

Comment: `-eq` es usado para comparaciones entre numeros, el c;odigo lo he probado con cadenas de texto, por eso uso el `==`

Comment: me arroja error el bash con el `==` tuve que cambiarlo, trabajo en una version de bash  muy primitiva mucho antes del año 95, no tiene las actualizaciones mas reciente que podemos encontrar en cualquier bash de hoy en dia.

Comment: @Guillermo `==` es sintaxis específica de versiones más nuevas de Bash. Tengo entendido que `=` sería la opción correcta, pues es la que acepta POSIX, pero desconozco si funcione en tu versión. De cualquier forma, te recomiendo probarla porque `-eq` es para comparaciones aritméticas y no para comparaciones de cadenas de texto.